# How does a nap affect nighttime sleep duration?

Tags: sleep

How does a nap of the kind that is often recommended – that is, early afternoon and no more than 30 minutes – affect nighttime sleep, especially the duration of nighttime sleep, but also its quality?

A similar question was asked [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/10681/if-you-sleep-during-the-day-do-you-need-less-sleep-at-night), but it referred to much longer daytime sleep, which is generally not recommended.

Comment: The answer to the question you linked mentioned stage 1 and stage 2 sleep which covers the first 30 minutes. How does that not help with your question?

Comment: That’s true, but that answer doesn’t say anything about the effect on nighttime sleep, which was my question.